# How to find files with the same name and remove all but the newest one in windows from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-tool

I want to keep only the newest version of the files with the same name in a folder and subfolders.
In other words, I want to remove duplicate files in a folder and subfolders, considering only that two files are duplicates when they have the same name (and extension) and keep only the one that has the newest modification date.

I know I can do it manually with programs like CCleaner or Nirsoft's SearchMyFiles but they don't have the posibility to select all but the newest one for deleting them, you have to do it manually.

So is there a command line tool, or cmd bat or powershell to accomplish this task?

Comment: Since you cannot have more than one file of the same name in a folder, do you mean files of the same name in sub folders of a folder?

Comment: Do you already know the 'same name' that you want to delete?

Comment: Do the "same name" files have different file extensions?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean in the folder and subfolders, and I mean same name and extension. I want to remove duplicate files, considering only that two files are duplicates when the have the same name (and extension) and keep only the newest one.

Comment: writing a file for you since I need this too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a program for you here: https://github.com/ITCMD/Remove-Duplicates

`DelDupe /?` output:

```
Deletes duplicate Files except the latest edited.

DelDupe  "Directory" "Filename" /F /C Character

Directory:      Directory to search for duplicate names. Use C:\Users\IT Command\Documents\Batch Codes\Keep Recent Mod Date for current dir.
Filename:       Duplicated Filename to search for
/F              Do not prompt removal
/C              Provide your own system character: The default character it uses to seperate files is ~. You don't need to know what this means, but if you have the ~ character in your filename then supply your own.
Character:      The Character you want to use instead of ~

Example:
  DelDupe "C:\Users\IT Command\Documents\Batch Codes\Keep Recent Mod Date" "Picture.png"

This example will surch all subdirectories in your current folder for a file called "Picture.png" and will delete all copies except for the most recently modified one.

Created by Lucas Elliott   www.itcommand.tech
```

Note that this is not a site to ask people to make full scripts for you. People get mad if you don't show that you've tried (I know you probably don't know where to start). It's okay to ask a question like you did in my opinion, but don't always expect a full answer. I just needed this for me anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer and the script. But the file name is not a parameter in my question. I want to keep only last version of every file in the tree of directories. I can't test it right now, but do you think something like: `forfiles /p folder /s /c "cmd /c DelDupe folder @path"` will work?

Comment: Anyway, I thought this was a common task and there would be some command line tool (exe) but the ones I found like FindDupe or Dupemerge are for exact duplicates and remove them or hardlink them. About the GUI tools like CCleaner and SearchMyFiles, I finally found one that automatically keep only last version for all the files with the same name: CloneSpy. But I prefer to do it from the command line. So thanks again for your code and I'll see how to do it with it.

Comment: glad to hear it!

Comment: Hi, I'm testing DelDupe and I had to modify line 56 to: if /i not defined force. But I'm sorry to say that it does not keep the last modified file. It keeps one of the other files.

Comment: Hmmm I’ll take a look sorry about that.

Comment: If it was modified within a minute it can’t tell

Comment: I have 6 files with the same name in subfolders with these modification dates: (20120401-122640) (20120120 134232) (20111215 070716) (20120910 064302) (20130723 112316) (20130720 061758) and it keeps the one (20120910 064302)

Comment: I found why deldupe does not work for me: my format date is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Hmm okay. I need to figure out how to handle different dates. Thank you for telling me!

Comment: OK, I already changed the code to work with my format. Another thing not working was that it always deletes the files when you answer N. I think you have to change line 60 to `if !errorlevel!==2 goto cleanup`. And finally I found that running `DelDupe "rootdir" "name"` when there is a subdirectory "rootdir\name\" with the same name that you give to deldupe it wants to remove all the files inside it and doesn't search for other files in the other subdirectories.

Comment: Oh whoops sorry!!!! That’s a big one.

Comment: Hi, using the tool where.exe instead of dir in line 17 `where /r "%PathN%" "%FileName%" >"%TEMP%\%ran%.ITCMD.log"` solved the second one if I'm not wrong. Another thing I found is that if the file name begins with _ it deletes all the files even the most recent.

Comment: Yikes. Well I’m just gonna retire now :D